# No funciona atributo "download" en etiqueta "a" en html

Tags: html

Al momento de querer implementar la descarga de un archivo directo en el ordenador local con el atributo `download`, en lugar de descargar, me abre el documento en otra pestaña, estuve buscando y realmente se hace así, entonces no sé si debería hacer alguna otra configuración previa.

Adjunto el código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="es"> 
<head> 
 <title>Este texto es el título del documento</title> 
 <meta charset="utf-8"> 
 <meta name="description" content="Este es un documento HTML5"> 
 <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, JavaScript"> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="misestilos.css"> 
</head> 
<body> 
 <header id="titulo"> 
 Este es el título 
 </header> 
 <nav> 
 Principal | Fotos | Videos | Contacto 
 </nav> 
 <main> 
 <section> 
    <article> 
 <footer> 
 <a download="Prueba 1" href="http://www.formasterminds.com/content/miarchivo.pdf" >Clic</a> 
 </footer> 
</article> 

 </section> 
 </main> 
 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Te descarga el archivo, lo que pasa es que tu navegador está configurado para abrir los archivos PDF directamente.

Comment: No había considerado revisar ha detalle este punto, entonces me fui a la configuración y tenía habilitada la opción de solo abrir archivos PDF y la habilite para descargar y funcionó.

Comment: Me percaté que ahora sin usar la el atributo download, todo archivo se descarga.

Answer (score 1):

El atributo de descarga `download` solo funciona si la URL de descarga es la misma del sitio. Entonces, si el `href` de tu archivo a descargar no está en tu sitio, la descarga no funcionará, en su lugar simplemente te redirigirá al enlace.

En otras palabras, solo puede descargar archivos que pertenezcan a tu sitio web. Es por ello que no te funciona, ya que el archivo al que apuntas no está en tu sitio.

Puedes ver más detalles en la [documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download).

Comment: Probé con un archivo que ya tenía en mi ordenador y de igual forma me abría el documento.

Comment: Estuve revisando la opcíon que me indicó @JoséCarlosPHP y modifqué la configuración de mi navegador (en mi caso estoy usando Chrome), solo habilité la opción para permitir descarga y funcionó, el detalle es que ahora incluso sin usar el atributo download en la etiqueta "a", todos los archivos se descargan.